# How do I format numbers in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help formatting numbers in a specific way.

If a number has three decimal places or less, I would like it to remain the same.

If a number has more than three significant figures, I would like all numbers after the third significant figure to be the fractional part of the number.

```
123 --> Stays the same
1234 --> 123.4
```

How can this be done?

EDIT:

```
1234567 --> 123.4567
```

I am on SQL 2007, wishing to UPDATE the value in the table. The value is stored as a numeric.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Did you just want to SELECT this for formatting sake, or did you want to UPDATE those values back to the table?

Comment: For `1234567` number, should the result be `123.4567` or `123.456.7`?

Comment: SQL 2007 I believe, Update the value, 123.4567

Comment: Is original value numeric or string?

Comment: The original value is a numeric

Comment: Decimal Place: The position of a digit to the right of a decimal point. I think you need to make correction in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a numeric solution:

```
UPDATE T SET NUM = NUM/POWER(10,FLOOR(LOG10(NUM))-2)
WHERE NUM>=1000
```

Or the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT NUM, CASE WHEN NUM<1000 THEN NUM
    ELSE NUM/POWER(10,FLOOR(LOG10(NUM))-2) 
    END AS NewNUM
FROM T
```

Note that the exact results can vary depending on the data type of NUM.  If it is a FLOAT field, it might round the last decimal if NUM gets too large.  If it is of type NUMERIC, it will add zero's to the end.  If DECIMAL, you need to be careful of the precision.  Note that this applies to all the update solutions already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This could work

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN Num > 999 THEN Num/10
   ELSE
      Num
   END As Num
```

There could be a better way, but this is what I could think of

Comment: This would not work for numbers greater than 9999 since numbers 10000-99999 would need to be divided by 100 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with strings.

```
CREATE TABLE T
( NUM NUMERIC(38,19) );

INSERT INTO T (NUM) VALUES ( 123456789 );
INSERT INTO T (NUM) VALUES ( 12345 );
INSERT INTO T (NUM) VALUES ( 123 );
INSERT INTO T (NUM) VALUES ( 1 );


SELECT CAST(
   CASE WHEN NUM < 999 THEN CAST(FLOOR(NUM) AS VARCHAR) 
        ELSE SUBSTRING(CAST(NUM AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) + '.' 
           + SUBSTRING(CAST(FLOOR(NUM) AS VARCHAR), 4, LEN(CAST(NUM AS VARCHAR)) - 3) 
    END AS NUMERIC(38, 19))
FROM T

UPDATE T
SET NUM = CAST(CASE WHEN NUM < 999 THEN CAST(FLOOR(NUM) AS VARCHAR) 
        ELSE SUBSTRING(CAST(NUM AS VARCHAR), 1, 3) + '.' 
           + SUBSTRING(CAST(FLOOR(NUM) AS VARCHAR), 4, LEN(CAST(NUM AS VARCHAR)) - 3) 
    END AS NUMERIC(38, 19));
```

I've put a working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38b0a/21) on SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming strings of only integer values:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(Num) <= 3 THEN Num
    ELSE STUFF(Num,4,0,'.')
    END
FROM (VALUES('1234567'),('123'),('1234'),('12')) t(Num) --some sample values
```

Result:

```
123.4567
123
123.4
12
```

Comment: I like the use of STUFF. For SQL server, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

[I answered this on a cross-post elsewhere](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/special-formatting-of-numbers), but for completeness:

```
WITH n(r) AS (
  SELECT 123 UNION ALL SELECT 1234 UNION ALL SELECT 1234567
)
SELECT LEFT(r, 3) + CASE 
  WHEN LEN(r) > 3 THEN '.' + SUBSTRING(RTRIM(r),4,38) ELSE '' END 
FROM n;
```